# Stargazer on pgmm objects

Tags: r, html-table, stargazer

I want to create a table using `stargazer` in R.
In the table, I want to present my GMM results (I used the `pgmm` function in the `plm` package).

However, the statistics are not directly reported using this formula:

```
stargazer(GMM_MODELS, title = "GMM Results",type = "html", 
          column.labels = c("Result 1", "Result 2", "Result 3"),
          out = "C:\\RESULTS.html")
```

It only shows this:
[image]

1. My only option right now is to work around and add more lines manually. But I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

2. Additionally, the number of observations is not the total of observations I have in my total dataset. I understand that this is the number of panels, but how can I directly add the number of total observations to my table?

Comment: `plm` models are supported by the `modelsummary` package https://modelsummary.com/articles/modelsummary.html